# Predict is not usbale for mira/mipo?

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I'm a student who have no prior knowledge in anything coding related but I'm taking a module that requires RStudio and now I'm struggling.

I have an assignment that needed us to explore the methods of dealing with missing data in training data set and test data set (multiple rows and multiple variables) and then creating a linear model `lm` using training set. Then, use `predict` with the said `lm` with newdata = test data to observe the results. I am tasked to learn how to use `MICE` to deal with this assignment but I am at a dead end.

In my attempt, I tried to fill up missing data of the training data set via `MICE` with my approach as follows:

```
train = read.csv("Train_Data.csv", na.strings=c("","NA"))
missingtraindata = mice(train, m=5, maxit = 5, method = 'pmm')
model = with(missingtraindata, lm(LOS~.- PatientID, data = train))
miceresults = pool(model)
summary(miceresults)
```

Then I tried to use `predict()` but it doesn't work because it says mira/mipo doesn't work with `predict()`. I don't know what that means at all.

Honestly I have no idea what any of these codes do, I just tried to apply whatever information available from the notes that I have regarding `MICE`. I don't know if that's how you correctly use MICE to fill up missing data but i literally spent the entire day researching and trying but it's of no help. Please helppppp!